# How To Parse Nested JSON and Load with Bootstrap Javascript Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing code that run at python, json data is passed from python to javascript.

JSON data is in nested mode as such:

```
var = {'a': { 'type':'1', 'value':'2'}, 'b': {'length':'2', 'location':'south'}}
```

expected output:

```
table a:
<table>
<tr>
<th>type</th><th>value</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>1<td>2
</tr>
</table>
```

```
table b:
<table>
<tr>
<th>length</th><th>location</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>2<td>south
</tr>
</table>
```

how to use json data above and use bootstrap table load to make as a table after tt

I know how to use in single json data such:

```
var = {'a': '1', 'b':'2'}
```

in javascript:

```
obj = JSON.parse(result);
$('#tablename').bootstrapTable('load',obj);
```

output:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>a</th><th>b</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>1<td>2
</tr>
</table>
```

but how to use for nested json like above to feed to 2 different table?

Comment: Can you add a sample row of the output table to the question as it is not clear how you want it represented.

Comment: hi @justinfay added sample row of the output